# Compare 10 Million Entities

Tags: c#, algorithm, matching

I have to write a program that compares 10'000'000+ Entities against one another. The entities are basically flat rows in a database/csv file.

The comparison algorithm has to be pretty flexible, it's based on a rule engine where the end user enters rules and each entity is matched against every other entity.

I'm thinking about how I could possibly split this task into smaller workloads but I haven't found anything yet. Since the rules are entered by the end user pre-sorting the DataSet seems impossible.

What I'm trying to do now is fit the entire DataSet in memory and process each item. But that's not highly efficient and requires approx. 20 GB of memory (compressed).

Do you have an idea how I could split the workload or reduce it's size?

Thanks

Comment: Each entity has to be compared with *every* other entity? Are you sure? That's ~5x10^13 combinations... If you could perform one million comparisons per second, it would take more than one and a half years to do.

Comment: Is this Rule Engine already written? This seems like work better suited to a database than C#

Comment: Pretty much. If I knew the rules how theese entities are compared now I could drastically reduce the workload. But I have no idea how exactly they're going to define the matching rules

Comment: Yes I wrote it already. Database was always an option but how do you define the rules in the database? The end-user needs a pretty simple interface and I haven't found anything that would fit my needs yet

Comment: You're right :/ Comparing all items against one other seems impossible. But the question remains on how to partition the data or just minimize the workload

Comment: Impossible to answer given that "the rules are entered by the end user".

Comment: Yes that's exactly my problem :) I have to make some restrictions. E.g. enter some criterias right from the beginning. This will restrict the user a little but could reduce the workload massively.

Comment: Can you give a typical example of the rules? Or at least their syntax?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your rules are on the highest level of abstraction (e.g. any unknown comparison function), you can't achive your goal. 10^14 comparison operations will run for ages.

If the rules are not completely general I see 3 solutions to optimize different cases:

- **if comparison is transitive and you can calculate hash** (somebody already recommended this), do it. Hashes can also be complicated, not only your rules =). Find good hash function and it might help in many cases.
- **if entities are sortable**, sort them. For this purpose I'd recommend not sorting in-place, but build an array of indexes (or IDs) of items. If your comparison can be transformed to SQL (as I understand your data is in database), you can perform this on the DBMS side more efficiently and read the sorted indexes (for example 3,1,2 which means that item with ID=3 is the lowest, with ID=1 is in the middle and with ID=2 is the largest). Then you need to compare only adjacent elements.
- **if things are worth**, I would try to use some heuristical sorting or hashing. I mean I would create hash which not necessarily uniquely identifies equal elements, but can split your dataset in groups between which there are definitely no one pair of equal elements. Then all equal pairs will be in the inside groups and you can read groups one by one and do manual complex function calculation in the group of not 10 000 000, but for example 100 elements. The other sub-approach is heuristical sorting with the same purpose to guarantee that equal elements aren't on the different endings of a dataset. After that you can read elements one by one and compare with 1000 previous elements for example (already read and kept in memory). I would keep in memory for example 1100 elements and free oldest 100 every time new 100 comes. This would optimize your DB reads. The other implementation of this may be possible also in case your rules contains rules like (Attribute1=Value1) AND (...), or rule like (Attribute1 < Value2) AND (...) or any other simple rule. Then you can make clusterisation first by this criterias and then compare items in created clusters.

By the way, what if your rule considers all 10 000 000 elements equal? Would you like to get 10^14 result pairs? This case proves that you can't solve this task in general case. Try making some limitations and assumptions.

Answer (score 4):

I would try to think about rule hierarchy.
Let's say for example that rule A is "Color" and rule B is "Shape".

If you first divide objects by color,
than there is no need to compare Red circle with Blue triangle.

This will reduce the number of compares you will need to do.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a hashcode from each entity. You probably have to exclude the id from the hash generation and then test for equals. If you have the hashs you could order all the hashcodes alphabetical. Having all entities in order means that it's pretty easy to check for doubles.

Comment: Sure, but the RuleSet can contain complex rules. You can't just compare the rows. (E.g. you want to normalize strings, calculate string distances etc.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare each entity with all entities than effectively you need to cluster the data , there is very fewer reasons to compare totally unrelated things ( compare Clothes with Human does not make sense) , i think your rules will try to cluster the data.

so you need to cluster the data , try some clustering algorithms like [K-Means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering).

Also see ,  [Apache Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org/)

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for the best suitable sorting algorithm, kind of a, for this? 
I think Divide and Concur seems good.
If the algorithm seems good, you can have plenty of other ways to do the calculation. Specially parallel processing using MPICH or something may give you a final destination.

But before decide how to execute, you have to think if algorithm fits first.